# Configuring validation tooltips with angular-ui

Tags: angularjs, tooltip, angular-ui

I am doing a simple form using angularjs with angular-ui.   Somehow angular is inserting boostrap tooltips into my validation. But it is getting inserted automatically and I do not know how to control/customize or disable the tooltips.  Here is my html:

```html
<form name="frm" ng-submit="contact.contactUsSubmit(frm)">

                                <table id="tblContactUs">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td id="tblContactUsTitleTd">
                                            Send us an email
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <span class="LabelStyle1">Name:</span><br/>
                                            <input type="text" tooltip-trigger="0" name="name" style="width: 75%" ng-model="contact.formInfo.name" required/><br/>
                                            <span ng-show="frm.name.$dirty && frm.name.$error.required" class="errorMsg">Required!<br /></span>
                                            <span class="LabelStyle1">Email:</span> <br/>
                                            <input type="email" name="email" style="width: 75%" ng-model="contact.formInfo.email" required/><br/>
                                            <span ng-show="frm.email.$dirty && frm.email.$error.required" class="errorMsg">Required!<br /></span>
                                            <span ng-show="frm.email.$dirty && frm.email.$error.email" class="errorMsg">Not a valid email!<br /></span>
                                            <span class="LabelStyle1">Message:</span> <br/>
                                            <textarea name="message" rows="5" style="width: 100%" ng-model="contact.formInfo.message" required></textarea><br/>
                                            <span ng-show="frm.email.$dirty && frm.name.$error.required" class="errorMsg">Required!</span>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="text-align: right">
                                            <button>Submit</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>



                            </form>
```

:

But I am getting this:

[image]

Yes the tooltip is nice.  But I didn't say I wanted it there.   IF I want to use the tooltip for validation, I need to be able to customize the message (for different languages).   I have googled the bejesus out the topic but I can't find answers as to how to configure it or to turn it off. I don't even know why its there in the first place.   Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Those aren't bootstrap or even css related in any way.

They are html5 validation tooltips that are part of the browser itself.

If you don't want to use built in browser validation add the `novalidate` attribute to `<form>` tag.

```
<form name="frm" ng-submit="contact.contactUsSubmit(frm)" novalidate>
```

Reference [MDN <form> docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!   However, when I put "novalidate" in the form tag you can hit submit and the angular validation does not fire, i.e. i can then submit the form without any data or with incorrect data.

Comment: `ng-submit` shouldn't fire when form not valid ... as a safe guard can check the `$valid` property of form object. What is `contact`? Is that a controller alias? If so should be part of the form `name` also

Comment: OK... the form validation object will get added to controller scope based on it's `name` so name should include controller object also.

Comment: In this case the form name is "frm."   i tried referencing $scope.frm but it was undefined.  So I passed the "frm" object into ng-submit="contact.contactUsSubmit(frm)".  Unfortunately, with "novalidate" set, my validation rules don't fire with ng-submit.  They only fire after user leaves field (on blur).

Comment: should be `contact.frm` since you have controller alias...then safe check would be in controller to check the `$valid` property. Also need to fix all the validation messages

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to charlietfl for putting me on the right track with "novalidate."  The problem with novalidate, however, is that when you hit ng-submit none of the validation error messages showed up.

The complete solution was to add the following code to the form tag ("contact" an alias for "contactController":

```html
<form name="frm" ng-submit="contact.formIsValid(frm) && contact.contactUsSubmit(frm)" novalidate>
```

In the controller the two functions went as follows:

```js
        formIsValid(frm) {
            
            angular.forEach(frm.$error.required, function (field) {
                field.$setDirty();
            });

            return frm.$valid;

        }

contactUsSubmit(frm) {
            var scope = this;
            if (frm.$valid) {
                //do $http post data etc here

               
            }



            return frm.$valid;
        }
```

Now, if when someone hits submit, the field are made "dirty" and this causes the angular validation rules to fire.   If the form is valid then the submit goes thru, if not then we are left with the validation errors.